# HtmlUnit AJAX response is partial HTML. Its failing parsing

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, htmlunit

The response of an AJAX response in HtmlUnit is a single div, which contains a table of data.

The response also contains a small JS script.

The problem is that HtmlUnit is trying to parse the response as a complete HTML. So, it expects that snippet to have all JS libraries like jQuery.

Is there a way to parse the snippet in the context of the parent page which fired the AJAX?

Alternatively, it would be ok if I just got the response as plain text. But, the request has to be within the session, along with all the Html headers intact.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the AJAX url can't be used for getPage. Instead, I loaded the outer page once, and triggered a script on that page, which loaded the AJAX response into a div.

```
String jsCommand = "$('#results_box').load( '"+ pageLink +"',"+ formdata +");";
parentPage.executeJavaScript(jsCommand);
```